# Изображение переворачивается зеркально, относительно горизонта BMP->YUV420

Tags: c++, bmp, rgb

читаю по пикселям RGB и заношу все в буфер (одномерный массив с размером ширину на высоту)
этот буфер записываю в бинарный файл. Как он есть.. (std::ofstream)
парсинг бмп взял от сюда
https://ziggi.org/chtenie-bmp-v-c-versiya-2/

вот код записи в буфер

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < fileInfoHeader.biHeight; i++)
{
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < fileInfoHeader.biWidth; j++)
    {
        read(fileStream, bufer, fileInfoHeader.biBitCount / 8);

        unsigned char r = rgbInfo[i][j].rgbRed = bitextract(bufer, fileInfoHeader.biRedMask);
        unsigned char g = rgbInfo[i][j].rgbGreen = bitextract(bufer, fileInfoHeader.biGreenMask);
        unsigned char b = rgbInfo[i][j].rgbBlue = bitextract(bufer, fileInfoHeader.biBlueMask);
        rgbInfo[i][j].rgbReserved = bitextract(bufer, fileInfoHeader.biAlphaMask);


        // well known RGB to YUV algorithm
        int Y = ((66 * r + 129 * g + 25 * b + 128) >> 8) + 16;
        int U = ((-38 * r - 74 * g + 112 * b+ 128) >> 8) + 128;
        int V = ((112 * r - 94 * g - 18 * b + 128) >> 8) + 128;

        frame[i * fileInfoHeader.biWidth + j] = Y;
        frame[(i / 2) * (fileInfoHeader.biWidth / 2) + (j / 2) + size] = U;
        frame[(i / 2) * (fileInfoHeader.biWidth / 2) + (j / 2) + size + (size / 4)] = V;

        index++;

    }
    fileStream.seekg(linePadding, std::ios_base::cur);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

А вы возьмите и переверните:

```
const unsigned h = fileInfoHeader_biHeight,
    w = fileInfoHeader_biWidth;
unsigned k = (h - 1) * w;
for (unsigned i = 0; i < h / 2 ; ++i) {
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < w; ++j) {
        std::swap(frame[i * w + j], frame[k + j]);          
    }
    k -= w;
}
```

Comment: Но так же не получится. Тогда переворачивать изначально картинку до конвертации. Либо каждый из блоков yuv (их три )

Comment: может и нет,  но перевернуть то получится по любому, или же считывать пиксели учитывая  их нулевую точку

Answer (score 0):

нашел как перевернуть, но есть ли способ попроще, без таких извращений?

```
struct RGBQUAD {
    unsigned char  rgbBlue;
    unsigned char  rgbGreen;
    unsigned char  rgbRed;
    unsigned char  rgbReserved;
};

// rgb info
RGBQUAD **rgbInfo = new RGBQUAD*[fileInfoHeader.biHeight];
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < fileInfoHeader.biHeight; i++) {
    rgbInfo[i] = new RGBQUAD[fileInfoHeader.biWidth];
}
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < fileInfoHeader.biHeight; i++)
{
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < fileInfoHeader.biWidth; j++)
    {
        read(fileStream, bufer, fileInfoHeader.biBitCount / 8);

        rgbInfo[i][j].rgbRed = bitextract(bufer, fileInfoHeader.biRedMask);
        rgbInfo[i][j].rgbGreen = bitextract(bufer, fileInfoHeader.biGreenMask);
        rgbInfo[i][j].rgbBlue = bitextract(bufer, fileInfoHeader.biBlueMask);
        rgbInfo[i][j].rgbReserved = bitextract(bufer, fileInfoHeader.biAlphaMask);

    }
    fileStream.seekg(linePadding, std::ios_base::cur);
}

// отзеркалить массив относительно средней строки
for (int i = 0; i < fileInfoHeader.biHeight / 2; ++i) {
    std::swap(rgbInfo[i], rgbInfo[fileInfoHeader.biHeight - i - 1]);
}

int size = fileInfoHeader.biHeight * fileInfoHeader.biWidth;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < fileInfoHeader.biHeight; i++)
{
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < fileInfoHeader.biWidth; j++)
    {
        //read(fileStream, bufer, fileInfoHeader.biBitCount / 8);

        unsigned char r = rgbInfo[i][j].rgbRed;
        unsigned char g = rgbInfo[i][j].rgbGreen;
        unsigned char b = rgbInfo[i][j].rgbBlue;

        // well known RGB to YUV algorithm
        int Y = RGB2Y(r, g, b);
        int U = RGB2U(r, g, b);
        int V = RGB2V(r, g, b);

        frame[i * fileInfoHeader.biWidth + j] = Y;
        frame[(i / 2) * (fileInfoHeader.biWidth / 2) + (j / 2) + size] = U;
        frame[(i / 2) * (fileInfoHeader.biWidth / 2) + (j / 2) + size + (size / 4)] = V;

    }
    fileStream.seekg(linePadding, std::ios_base::cur);
}
```

и того мы имеем три цикла, получаем массив пикселей, переворачиваем, и конвертируем в yuv420. Бред. Можно ли это как то сделать подругому?